# Sage REPL Specify IPython Binary

Tags: python, math, sage

Sage only works with python2, but I'm running python3 on my system in a virtual environment. Whenever I try to start the sage REPL, it fails saying module "sage" not found. When I open python2 directly and import sage, it works. So it seems like sage is trying to use python3 and failing. It's probably using my PATH env variable, but I don't want to change this every time I start up the REPL. How can I tell it to use a specific version of python/ipython?

Comment: Sage uses "its own" version of Python, so I'm not sure how you would even use a system Python with Sage.  Also, Sage doesn't (yet) work with Python 3 - see http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/15980

Comment: It looks like it is trying to load python3 libraries though, I straced it, and it looks like it is using something from my virtualenvironment

Comment: Yea, all the sage binaries have shebangs at the top that are /usr/bin/env python, and if this is python3, it will fail because python3 doesn't have sage installed.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the Sage REPL from the Sage shell (run `sage -sh` and start the Sage REPL from there). Then it would use Sage's Python.